# Hibernate object re-loading from database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, dbunit

I have a Spring + Hibernate + DBUnit + MySQL application.

The steps are the following:

```
1. I launch the application.
2. A DBUnit test loads data directly into the database (via JDBC).
3. I perform operations and HQL queries to assert the results.
```

Immediately after step 2, I query the database from a console and I confirm that data has correctly been loaded. My problem is that in step 3, the object I get through an HQL query doesn't contain the value loaded in step 2 but the original one (the one which existed in step 1 and before).

After reading some posts here, I decided to clean the session cache and the second-level cache before step 3, in order to force Hibernate to a direct database fetch. But the problem still persists.

Is there something I am doing wrong?

Here is a script I am trying in step 3:

Before application launching (step 1), the account balance in the database is 125. In step 2, DBUnit does change that balance in database to 10.

```
   // A break-point here allows me to check through a console that balance at database is cartainly 10.

   // I query the account and print the balance, which is 125.
   List l1 = this.getHibernateTemplate().find("select a from Account a where a.number = ?", parameter);
   Account account1 = (Account) l1.get(0);
   System.out.println("A.- Account 1 balance: " + account1.getBalance());

   // I clear session cache and second-level cache.
   this.getSession().evict(account1);
   this.getSessionFactory().evict(Account.class);       
   this.getSessionFactory().evictQueries();     

   // I repeat the same query, now expecting to force a database fetch. But it still prints 125 and not 10.
   List l2 = this.getHibernateTemplate().find("select a from Account a where a.number = ?", parameter);
   Account account2 = (Account) l2.get(0);
   System.out.println("B.- Account 2 balance: " + account2.getBalance());
```

I've also tried refresh(account1) and session.clear(), but they didn't work.

If this is not the right solution, I am open to listen to other ones.

Thanks,
Diego.

Comment: when is the account balance supposed to change here? you should be using a new transaction/session if you expect different results

Comment: This script is incuded within a transaction context provided by Spring for each service. After loading the data, dbunit calls this service, opening a new transaction context.

Comment: Jess, you are right. I've tried what you said and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think your are seeing this behavior because your transaction is configured in REPEATABLE_READ. This means that Hibernate guarantees that two reads within the same transaction will always return the same result. As the isolation level takes precedence on your cache eviction, the cache evict doesn't have any visible effect.

**There is a ways to work around this behavior:**
Declare your transaction isolation level to READ_UNCOMMITTED or READ_COMMITTED. You might run into the famous "Standard JPA does not support custom isolation levels" exception if you are using a standard dialect. In which case you can apply the following workaround: 
spring 3.3:http://amitstechblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/supporting-custom-isolation-levels-with-jpa/
spring 3.2:http://shahzad-mughal.blogspot.com/2012/04/spring-jpa-hibernate-support-for-custom.html

Answer (score -1):

i don't know about hibernate, but this is what shuold be done using JPA:

```
public <T> T load(Class<T> entityClass, Object pk)
{
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put("javax.persistence.cache.retrieveMode", CacheRetrieveMode.BYPASS);

    return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, pk, props);
}
```